# Java: Index Select in ComboBox in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Hey I have a `JTable` that has a `Combobox` as a `cellEditor`. I have values in that Table and I added a Combobox and I need to have the value in the cell be the selected index of the combobox.

```
     DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rows,columes);

        //Select combobox values
        Object[] string = (Object[]) sqlSTypes.executeSqlSelectOneDimension(sql);

        if(string != null) {
            comboBoxtypes  = new JComboBox<Object>(string);
        }

        if( comboBoxtypes != null) {
            dealPositionsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor((TableCellEditor) new DefaultCellEditor(comboBoxtypes));
        }
```

Comment: `DefaultCellEditor` already handles this for you. Please provide information on what behaviour you are experiencing. Also please provide a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to add rows of a comboBox in your code. I'm assuming you have figured out how to add the row and the row value that you want, based off of your cell data. Next you'll need to set the selected index of the comboBox.

Once you get the value of the cell use:

```
setSelectedIndex( your index here )
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
setSelectedItem( your item here )
```

If you know the value of the row in the comboBox.